# How to pass parameters using load jQuery

Tags: jquery, parameters

I'm trying to pass params in a child web included in a parent.

I'm using this in the parent:

```
$('#idElemet').load('myPage.html?param1='+value);
```

In the child web (myPage.html) to show the param value this:

```
alert(getURLParameter('param1'));

function getURLParameter(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea to read the params?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A child script loaded by and subsumed into a parent script adopts the parent's environment.

So in your child sscript, `location.search` points not to the path you used to load the child, but to the frame (or, if no frames, window) URL.

You cannot pass params to a script being loaded as you are currently trying to do. Instead, declare them in your parent script and have your child script read them from there, e.g.

Parent script:

```
var foo = 'bar';
$('#idElemet').load('myPage.html');
```

myPage.html:

```
<script>alert(foo); //"bar"</script>
```

Comment: A loop is generating div and call the load function on every div so the variable value is lost in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You can read params like so:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

# example.com?test=1&param1=heythere
$.urlParam('param1'); // heythere
$.urlParam('test');   // 1
```